# How to send binary payload via netcat in a pwn attack

Tags: buffer-overflow, ctf

On connecting to the exploit server via `netcat`, the server prompts for input. I have crafted my payload in the binary file `payload`, how can I send it to the server. I've tried `cat payload | nc ...` but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's like: How can I "type" binaries into the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by appending a '\n' to indicate end of input to `nc`